# How to access FlowRouter subscriptions in Meteor template helpers?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

it seems like I can't access a FlowRouter template subscription in my helper. How can you do this?

In my server code:

```
Meteor.publish('AllUsers', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
})
```

In my router code:

```
var userRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
        this.register('AllUsers', Meteor.subscribe('AllUsers'));
    },
});
```

In my template code:

```
{{#if checkFlowRouterSubs}}
    {{#each getTheUsers}}
        {{>userPartial}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

In my helpers I have the 'guard':

```
checkFlowRouterSubs: function() {
    if (FlowRouter.subsReady()) {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
},
```

And then the getTheUsers helper:

```
...
var users = AllUsers.find(filterObject, { sort: { 'profile.firstname': 1 } }).fetch(); // the actual query definitely works
...
```

But I get an error:

```
Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: AllUsers is not defined
```

I should note that in the getTheUsers helper, `FlowRouter.subsReady('AllUsers')` returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, first, this :

```
var userRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
        this.register('AllUsers', Meteor.subscribe('AllUsers'));
    },
});
```

is NOT server code: it is Client code: the Flow-router is a client side router: counter intuitive but this is the basis of all these routers. 
The hint here is that you are 'subscribing' to the publication in this code, so it is on the client side.

Iron-Router is routing both on the server and client-side so it makes things even more confusing when you come from there.

What you are missing here is the `publish` function on the server side.

```
Meteor.publish('AllUsers', function() {
    return AllUsers.find();
});
```

EDIT:

The Error

`Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: AllUsers is not defined` 
seems like because you did not define the collection on the client side

`var AllUsers = Mongo.Collection('AllUsers'); //or whatever the actual collection`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies for that mistake - I do actually have that in my server code. I've amended the question

Comment: seems like your collection is not defined on the client side.

Comment: Thank you that is probably the reason. I guess that you still need a local storage on the client side for the published collection

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get data from a subscription, you want to call the actual collection you're looking to get data for, not the subscription name.  In this case, I think you mean Meteor.users:

```
var users = Meteor.users.find(filterObject, { sort: { 'profile.firstname': 1 } });
if( users ) {
  return users.fetch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes get an undefined error when I do that in a helper, even when using a guard